# GNU grep regex `[一-十]` (one to ten) does not match the Chinese character 四 (four)

Tags: regex, grep, cjk

This command

```
$ echo '一二三四五六七八九十' | grep -oE '[一-十]'
```

outputs:

```
一
二
三
五
六
七
八
九
十
```

The regex `[一-十]` (one to ten) is expected to match against Chinese numbers.
As the example shows, it matches against every Chinese number from one to ten, except the Chinese character `四` (four)。

Why?

Is this a bug or a joke?

I may think this as joke, because in Chinese '四' (four) sounds alike '事' (thing). In fact, in some dialects of Chinese, they share a same pronunciation. Thus '一二三五六七八九十' (one two three five six seven eight nine ten) implies '沒四' (no four), i.e. '沒事' (no thing)。

BTW, the version of the grep I use:

```
GNU grep 2.5.4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Chinese numbers are not in order in Unicode. That 四 is U+56DB, while 一 is U+4E00, and 10 is 5341. So the 4 doesn't fit.

Read the Unicode standard for more information, and see http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U4E00.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Howerver, I use '-' (ascii, not Chinese characters) instead of '一'. So it matches against a range. Can you edit your answer? Then I can accept it.

Comment: @weakish bmargulies is talking about the first character of your range, not the dash between the endpoints.

Comment: @lanzz Thanks to point out my mistake. '一' and '——' looks similar. I should have noticed `U+4E00`.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this on a Chinese forum, and alvin_rxg  replies with this:

```
一 => U+4E00
十 => U+5341
四 => U+56DB
```

So I known I just made a silly assumption!
`grep` is not that smart.
The regex [一-十] (one to ten) is *not* expected to match against Chinese numbers.
It just matches any characters between '一' (U+4E00) and '十' (U+5341).
It just happens that all Chinese numbers are in that range except  '四' (U+56DB)!

This can be used as a cold joke, though. ;-)